# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ubuntu-core

When i tries to open Spider(python IDE), Every time i got this error Segmentation fault (core dumped) ,What should i do.I tried different methods but could not resolve. Should I reinstall it or what.

Comment: "Segmentation fault" indicates an out-of-range memory reference - trying to access location `0`, or accessing unallocated memory. It's a programming error. Not posting the properly formatted exact error message makes it impossible for us to further diagnose your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information...i solved my problem by updating the anaconda package  conda update --all